# How to share one common subprocesses between several Python process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

With `multiprocessing`, it's easy to have a subprocess and share information with it through queues. But if I need to share informations with this process from another Python process, how do I do that ? And how do I guaranty I have at least one and only one process of this nature running ?

E.G : I have a main process, an anti-virus process and a mail receiver process.

When I start the main process, it starts the anti-virus process and mail receiver process if, and only if, they are not running already. The main process can send files to the anti-virus process to check, but so can the mail receiver process.

Now, I know I can do this by manually coding socket handling for the the anti-virus process and make it accept commands using this, including a ping command and a kill command. But since multiprocessing can abstract this for a simple subprocess, is there any way it can do it for my purpose ? Or any easier way ? Any lib that would do ? Something generic would be much better than coding that myself.

Pure Python solution are prefered.

Comment: This sounds like an issue you can solve with shared memory. I'm not sure about the specifics of using shared memory with python but i'm sure you will find details with a bit of googling. You could also look at something like ZeroMQ which will provide you with a queue like on top of simple unix sockets which you could then use for IPC. You could also search for something like 'python IPC'

Comment: I think this might be what you are looking for: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ipc.html